# Can´t login after setting .htaccess file

Tags: php, html, mod-rewrite, authentication

I made a simple admin interface for one website and then I wanted to hide the .php from URL. But then the login stopped to work.

Login form (post method) is on page admin.php in root directory, after login it includes admin content from another file in protected directory.
What am I doing wrong?

.htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

EDIT: I noticed not only login form, but also all the ajax loaded modal dialogs aren´t sending data. Where I could, I removed redirections in forms and in ajax file I put url:file instead url:file.php where it was possible. And these corrections helped. But on some lines I need to have the extension written. So I can´t use this and still need some proper settings in .htaccess for these few cases.

Comment: Sounds like an overcomplicated and therefore very flimsy architecture, which is probably the reason why no one here wants to tackle it. I also suspect that your THE_REQUEST rewrite cond messes it up even more. Is there a particular reason not to keep this simpler and avoid the labyrinthine htaccess rules altogether?

Comment: I actually don´t understand single line of the code above, so I guess there is no reason to keep it complicated... I didn´t even know it is complicated :)) Anyway the answer below solved my problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made your .htaccess very complicated.
if only url-rewriting is your goal then you can do it simply by

*Replace YOUR_DIRECTORY by your folder name or remove it with slash.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ YOUR_DIRECTORY/$1.php [NC]
```

> Note :- There is no need to forbid requests with .php extension, because you have
>   sad that these files exists in another protected directory, then it
>   will automatically throw 404 error.

Comment: Im no friend with mod_rewrite, that code I just copied from somewhere when I searched how ho hide the .php. And there was the code I mentioned above. I don´t understand a single line of it :( But your code works, this really helped. Thanks!

Comment: One more question - I got a link in protected file, that redirects to homepage. And via this link, the .php extension is visible again. What to add to the code please?

Comment: @MichalS you can remove .php extension from all links, they will work fine. What about bounty ?

Comment: Removing the extension doesn´t work. I´ll give you the bounty for sure, but when I click on it it gives me message "You may award your bounty in 5 hours". So I guess we just have to wait.

Comment: @MichalS sorry dude but, can't help without viewing code.